# bcrypt-nodejs compare method returns false every time

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, bcrypt

I'm trying to make a login in for my app using mongoose, passport-local, and bcrypt-nodejs.

The userSchema pre('save') function works fine and saves a hashed password. however the bcrypt compare method will return false every time.

see  [bcrypt-nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs)

here is my userSchema

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    login:{
        local:{
            email: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
            password: {type: String, unique: true, required: true}
        }
    }


userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  bcrypt.hash('user.login.local.password', null, null,  function(err, hash){
        if(err){
            next(err);
        }
        console.log('hash', hash);
        user.login.local.password = hash;
        next();
     })
});

 userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password, cb){

    bcrypt.compare(password, this.login.local.password, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    })
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

this works fine, and saves a new user with a hashed password

here is my my login strategy

no matter what info the user inputs, this will always return false

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({

        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallBack: true
    },
    function(email, password, done){


        User.findOne({ 'login.local.email' : email }, function(err, user){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return done(err);
            }

            if(!user){
                console.log('no user found');
                return done(err);
            }


            user.validPassword(password, function(err,match){

                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    throw err;
                }
                console.log(password, match);
            })

        })
    }))
```

lastly my route

```
app.post('/user/login', passport.authenticate('local-login'{
        successRedirect: '/#/anywhereBUThere'
        failureRedirect: '/#/'
    }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the root of the problem is that the compare function is returning false because you are indeed comparing two non-identical hashes.

You appear to be passing in a string '*user.login.local.password*' instead of the actual password in your userSchema pre save function:

e.g. this
`bcrypt.hash('user.login.local.password', null, null,  function(err, hash){` should be `bcrypt.hash(user.login.local.password, null, null,  function(err, hash){` (no single-quotes on the password being passed in as the first parameter.)

Additionally, you're then setting the generated hash to a 'user' object which seems to live outside of your user model. I can't see that code, but I suspect that you're not updating the value of the hash on the user model being saved to mongoDB.

e.g.
`user.login.local.password = hash;`
should probably be
`this.login.local.password = hash;`

Comment: Ahhh man I feel like an idiot! thanks a lot Marco runnin smooth now! the problem was the quotes.  I never caught it because i logged out the user that it found and it showed a hashed password so I figured it was hashing the password I entered... what else would it be hashing??? any way thanks for your help, I am now 1 for 1 using stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where `bcrypt.compare()` is always returning `false`, turns out I was passing the arguments in an incorrect order, please make sure to pass the plain password as the first argument.

```
bcrypt.compare(plainPassword, hashedPassword)
```